# Kendo Dropdownlist not updating Kendo Grid datasource on first record?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui, datasource, kendo-grid

Here's my problem...

I wanted to have a dropdownlist bound to my Grid as such:

---

```
{
     field: "ContactTypeId",
     hidden: true
},
{
     field: "ContactTypeName",
     title: "Type",
     editor: ContactTypeAddressCombo
}
```

---

```
function ContactTypeAddressCombo(container, options) {
                $('<input placeholder="A" data-bind="value:ContactTypeId"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    autoBind: false,
                    dataTextField: "Name",
                    dataValueField: "ContactTypeId",
                    dataSource: {
                        type: "json",
                        serverFiltering: true,
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "../Services/svcContact_Type.asmx/Search",
                                dataType: "json",
                                cache: false
                            },
                            parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                options.AddressFlag = 1;
                                options.PhoneFlag = 1;
                                options.EmailFlag = 1;
                                return kendo.stringify(options);
                            }
                        },
                        schema: {
                            data: "d"
                        }
                    },
                    index: 0
                });
            }
```

---

Everything works perfectly, **EXCEPT** for when I add a new row to the grid. The dropdown loads fine and has one item selected, but unless I change to another item, the grid won't recognize the selected item (The datasource for the grid sends 0 even though an item is selected).

One solution would be to have the first item always a "Select one" with a 0 value, which would force the user to select an item. But that is far from ideal. So... any other suggestions? Does the dropdownlist has some kind of placeholder?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question is discussed multiple times on the internet and each user describes it in a different way. When creating a new item you should set default value so the MVVM framework can properly assign the selected value of the DropDownList or you should do it manually with the help of the edit event.

In other words - your model property should not be null - it should be string or a number or it wont be updated properly when you change the value with the DropDownList (the whole dataItem used for the by the DropDOwnList will be assigned as value).

**[Here](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mvc/grid/in-an-editable-grid-picking-the-first-value-in-a-foreignkey-column-shows-a-blank-cell.aspx)** is more information.